# Custom logger in Firestore to create statistics on operations?

Tags: javascript, firebase, logging, google-cloud-firestore

How can I sniff all traffic in Firestore JS SDK?

To explain in more detail, the following code enables verbose logging into console.

```js
import { setLogLevel } from 'firebase/firestore'
setLogLevel('debug')
```

Now, everytime a network communication happens, in the console there are outputs like:

> [2022-09-28T12:00:21.878Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.6.10): Connection WebChannel received:
> {"documentChange":{"document":{"name":"projects/mu-project/databases/(default)/documents/my_collection/sHM7OvtpEygAKQBawxha","fields":{ ...

Is it possible to subscribe to such logs with a custom callback, instead of printing it in console, so I can analyze the communication?

Something like:

```js
import { setLogLevel, setLogger } from 'firebase/firestore'
setLogLevel('debug')
setLogger((message, payload) => {
 // custom stuff
})
```

It is intended to create statistics on writes and reads, that are intended to be used on FE in realtime.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible in that you can build your own version of the SDK and make it do whatever you want.  It's [open source](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/tree/master/packages/firestore).

Otherwise, no, it's not possible.

You're probably better off instrumenting your own application code to make it capture the things it's doing with Firestore.

Answer (score 1):

I have found `onLog` function which can be used to register a callback on every produced log message. However, it does not solve the question precisely, because the function *does not intercept* the logging, and therefore, cannot mute the output to the console. It will produce a lot of debug messages which is not desired in the production deployment.

```js
import { onLog, setLogLevel } from 'firebase/app'

setLogLevel('debug') // must be used to track the traffic
onLog((args) => {
  console.log('Custom log callback: ', args)
}, {level: 'debug'})
```

Also note that `onLog` must be called after the Firestore component is initialized.